# Сортировка через связанные модели

Tags: django, django-filter

Нужно сделать сортировку для записей `Credit` через связанные с ними модели `CreditPayment`.

**models.py**

```
class Credit(models.Model):
    hot = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class CreditPayment(models.Model):
    credit = models.ForeignKey(Credit)
    period_to = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
```

**views.py**

```
credits = credits.filter(hot=False).distinct().order_by(...)
```

**Пример входных данных:**

```
Credit #1:
CreditPayment #1:
period_to = 12
rate = 10

CreditPayment #2:      (minimal)
period_to = 10
rate = 8

CreditPayment #3:      
period_to = 9
rate = 10
```

---

```
Credit #2:
CreditPayment #1:        (minimal)
period_to = 6
rate = 20

CreditPayment #2:
period_to = 9
rate = 20
```

---

```
Credit #3:
CreditPayment #1:
period_to = 12
rate = 8

CreditPayment #2:
period_to = 9
rate = 11

CreditPayment #3:       (minimal)
period_to = 9
rate = 8
```

В итоге, выборка уменьшается до:

```
Credit #1:    
CreditPayment #2:
period_to = 10
rate = 8
```

---

```
Credit #2:
CreditPayment #1:
period_to = 6
rate = 20
```

---

```
Credit #3:
CreditPayment #3:
period_to = 9
rate = 8
```

**Результат:**

*Credit #3 -> Credit #1 -> Credit #2*

Как видно, сначала были отобраны минимальные `CreditPayment` для каждого `Credit`. Затем уже по этим минимальным `CreditPayment` происходит сортировка всех `Credit`. Если `rate` у двух записей равны, сравниваем их по `period_to`. Насколько я понимаю, здесь нужно как-то применить *агрегацию*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил с помощью `prefetch_related` и `annotate`

**models.py**

```
class CreditPayment(models.Model):
    credit = models.ForeignKey(Credit, related_name='creditpayments')
    ....
```

**views.py**

```
from django.db.models import Min, Max, Prefetch

prefetch = Prefetch('creditpayments', CreditPayment.objects.all())
sorted_credits = Credit.objects.all().prefetch_related(prefetch).annotate(min_rate=Min('creditpayments__rate')).annotate(max_period_to=Max('creditpayments__period_to')).order_by('min_rate', '-max_period_to')
```

Comment: Попробуйте `Credit.objects.all().order_by("creditpayments__rate", "creditpayments__period_to)`, не уверен что при обратной связи будет работать, но попробуйте.

Comment: Пробовал так изначально. Не работает.

Comment: Закройте вопрос )

Answer (score 1):

Проверил, работает запрос без указания на множество(без "s"):

```
Credit.objects.all().order_by("creditpayment__rate", "creditpayment__period_to)
```

Хотя, в вашем случае, так как указано вручную имя для обратной связи, должно работать через него, то есть, мой вариант указанный в комментариях. Проверяйте лучше, в следующий раз.

Comment: Дело в том, что при таком запросе появляются почему-то дубликаты и `distinct` не работает. Пример вывода по Вашему запросу: `[<Credit: C>, <Credit: B>, <Credit: D>, <Credit: E>, <Credit: E>, <Credit: A>, <Credit: A>, <Credit: F>, <Credit: F>, <Credit: F>]`. Пример вывода по моему запросу: `[<Credit: C>, <Credit: B>, <Credit: D>, <Credit: E>, <Credit: A>,  <Credit: F>]`

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0, сортировка на выборку не влияет, только на сортировку.